# Run angularjs code sync and wait varibale for function result

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in angularjs and have issue with working sync in angular.
here is my code that want to fill the variable in controller with result of the fucntion, now it returns an empty object or undfined:

I want a solution for using services and use the result whenever they are ready, what should I do?

```
App.service("UserService",['$location',"$http","$timeout",function($location,$http,$timeout){
    var User={};
    var CheckAuthenticationURL="/fa/home/IsAuthenticate";
    if($location.protocol() == "https")
    {
      CheckAuthenticationURL="https://www.mytest.org/fa/home/IsAuthenticateSecure";
    }
    var UpdateUserData= function(){
      return $http.get(CheckAuthenticationURL)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          User=data;
        })
    };
    var getUser= function()
    {
      UpdateUserData();
      return User;
    }
    return{
      UpdateUserData: UpdateUserData,
      getUser: getUser
    };
  }]);

  App.controller('GeneralCtrl',['$scope','$http','UserService','$interval', function($scope,$http,UserService,$interval) {
    $scope.User={};
    $scope.User=UserService.getUser();
  }]);
```

Comment: `$http.get` is async, you can't make it become sync. You shouldn't be trying to get it to become sync anyway, you should only wait for the UserService to be populated before using it. Are you using `angular-route`,  `angular-route2` or `ui-router`?

Comment: @Camusensei:   So, what's  the solution for it? it ok to have it any time it come, but when the page loads, it set the value ot undefined and it's not updated after the result comes in

Comment: No, I'm not using none of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `User=data;` into `User.name=data;`.
Then, `$scope.User.name` will be changed whenever the response arrives.

Comment: I am not talking about `$scope` in the service, but in your controller.